# Right split for homomorphism onto $S_\infty$

Tags: gn.general-topology, homological-algebra, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$ and let $f:G\rightarrow S_\infty$ be a continuous surjective homomorphism. Under which conditions $f$ has a right split, i.e. there exists some $g:S_\infty\rightarrow G$ such that $g$ is a continuous homomorphism and $fg=id_{S_\infty}$?

**Added**: Alternatively, can you find a closed subgroup $G$ of $S_\infty$ such that for **all** $f:G\rightarrow S_\infty$, $f$ does not right split?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), $f:G\rightarrow S_\infty$ right splits iff $G$ is the semi-direct product of $ker(f)$ and $S_\infty$. So, the question is equivalent to finding some closed subgroup $G$ of $S_\infty$ such that $G$ is **not** the semi-direct product of any of its normal subgroups and $S_\infty$.

Comment: This sounds a bit general to me to expect any useful answer. Plenty of closed subgroups of $S_\infty$ admit such homomorphism $f$.

Comment: @YCor. This is not my area, so I am not sure. Looking around on the web, I found for instance that if $ker(f)$ is a complete group, i.e. $ker(f)$ has no outer automorphism and is centerless, then $f$ splits. It is true that $S_\infty$ is centerless and has no outer automorphisms. Does this imply the same is true for $ker(f)$?

Comment: No, it's not true. The result you mention is true in full generality. An example of a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf{Z})$ is the subgroup of odd permutations (= satisfying $f(-n)=-f(n)$ for all $n$. This naturally maps to $S_\infty$ with kernel isomorphic to the abelian group $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})^\mathbf{N}$, which has itself as a center and has plenty of (outer) automorphisms. Of course in this example, the extension is split.

Comment: Then do you think there is a counterexample? I.e. some $f$ as above that does not split?

Comment: I guess there are, but right now I can't see any.

Comment: Here's a counterexample (non-split $f$). Let $G=S_\infty$ act on $\mathbf{N}=\{0,1,\dots\}$ in the standard way. Then the amalgam $H=G_0\ast_{G_0\cap G_1} G_1$ is a Polish group with canonical a non-split homomorphism onto $G$ (induced by the standard inclusion $G_0\to G$, $G_1\to G$. Then $H$ has a basis of neighborhoods of identity neighborhoods consisting of open subgroups of countable index (the family $(G_0\cap G_1\cap\dots\cap G_n)_n$, and this implies that it's isomorphic to a closed subgroup of $S_\infty$ (see Proposition 4.1 here: http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~melleray/Rosendal.pdf).

Comment: @YCor: Can you be a little more explicit? What is $G_0,G_1,\ldots,G_n$?

Comment: $G_i$ is the stabilizer of $i\in\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you for the example. The definition of the amalgam is new to me. So, it will take a little while to understand it. (I looked it up on the web, but the definitions I found did not help me.) What I understand is that you have the free product of $G_0$ and $G_1$ and you "identify" the elements in $G_0\cap G_1$ on both sides. Then you map the whole amalgam onto $S_\infty$ by inclusion. I fail to see what will map to, say $(01)$, the permutation that switches $0$ and $1$.  (cont.)

Comment: You have to show that $G_0$ and $G_1$ generate $G$. SInce both are maximal subgroups, this is clear, but you can make it more explicit.

Comment: (cont.) I don't want to go into all the details here at the comments. So, let's assume that the example holds true. Then we have one $G$ and one $f$. In the "added" question, I asked if there is a $G$ so that all $f$'s do not split. I don't think this is the case here. Just map $G_0$ isomorphically to $S_\infty$.